# C program running on my machine but not remote server?

Tags: c

I'm a complete noob to C, and I'm having an issue. My program works on my machine, but fails on my schools remote machine where it will be graded. I have a suspicion that there is something corrupted on my school account, but also a good chance there is something wrong with my program.

This program takes in a CSV file of movie data with title, year, rating, and languages.

The function where I think there may be a problem effecting the memory is where I am supposed to print out the highest rated movie in each year. The best way to do this would be an array of hash maps for O(n) time, but since I'm new to C I took an easier approach. I did an O(n^2) loop through the movies (they are a linked list, which is required) and at each movie, I loop through the array to check if there is a higher rated movie for that year, then print it.

I also make a dynamic array that stores the "visited" years, so say if there are 2 2008 movies, it doesn't print both.

The program is fairly long, so I will just show the function I'm stuck on and then what one of the movie nodes looks like. I am passing in head of the linkedlist to the printHighestRated function.

```
struct movie
{
    /**
    * Node for each movie containing title, year, language, and release date.
    */
    char *title;
    char *year;
    char *languages;
    char *rating;
    struct movie *next;
};

bool ifIn(int curYear, int *p, int size)
    /**
    * Helper function to see if year has already been checked.
    */
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        if (*(p + i) == curYear)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void printHighestRated(struct movie *list)
    /**
    * Prints the highest rated movie for each year.
    * Loops through linked list in O(n^2) time to find the max rated movie for each year being considered.
    * Keeps a 'visited' array so that the same year isn't checked/printed twice.
    */
{
    int *visited;
    int i = 0;
    int arrSize = 1;
    visited = calloc(arrSize, sizeof(int));     // Dynamic array to track visited years
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        int curYear = atoi(list->year);
        if (!ifIn(curYear, visited, i))         // If year has not been checked, find and print the highest rated movie
        {
            char *ptr;
            struct movie *cur = list;
            double maxRating = strtod(cur->rating, &ptr);
            struct movie *maxMovie = cur;
            while (cur != NULL)
            {
                if (strtod(cur->rating, &ptr) > maxRating && atoi(cur->year) == curYear)    // If higher rated movie is found
                {
                    maxMovie = cur;
                    maxRating = strtod(cur->rating, &ptr);
                }
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            printf("%s %s %s\n", maxMovie->year, maxMovie->rating, maxMovie->title);
        }
        *(visited + i) = curYear;
        i ++;
        if (i == arrSize - 1)
        {
            visited = realloc(visited, 2 * arrSize);  // Resize visited array if needed
        }
        list = list->next;
    }
    free(visited);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These three statements are problematic:

```
*(visited + i) = curYear;
i ++;
if (i == arrSize - 1)
```

If we start with `i == 0` then

```
*(visited + i) = curYear;
```

will be okay since you access the first element of your one-element array.

Then you increase `i` so then `i == 2`.

Then you check if you need to increase the size of `visited`:

```
if (i == arrSize - 1)
```

But here's the problem, your comparison will be `2 == 1 - 1` which will be false and therefore you don't reallocate memory. So you will forever go out of bounds of the allocated memory for `visited`. Which of course leads to *undefined behavior*, and possible crashes.

The solution is to subtract from `i` instead of `arrSize`:

```
if (i - 1 == arrSize)
```

Or *add* one to `arrSize`:

```
if (i == arrSize + 1)
```

Also note that when you reallocate memory, you never increase `arrSize`, so no matter what you will only reallocate memory once.

---

Even on your local system where everything seems to work, this should have been quite easy to find out with a little debugging.

Take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Then you would have seen the code step over the reallocation, even though it was needed.